# Using :before (or similar) to insert dynamic coloured icon before LI

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty complex problem. I have a UL with a number of LI inside.

I need to insert a icon of sorts before the LI element.

The icon needs to be two parts, one PNG-image with a simple form, and an outer shape with a dynamic background color.

To be specific it supposed to be a round circle, with a simple icon inside. The circle background needs to be able to change with code.

The way I've solved it now is using a SPAN inside the LI element and setting:

```
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background: url(icon.png) 2px 2px no-repeat red;
border-radius: 20px
```

The problem is that I have to put a SPAN inside every LI, and that's not an option. I need to solve this somehow so I have a "clean" UL with just LIs inside of it.

This is what I have now:

```
<ul>
<li><span></span>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Though there can't be any other element except LIs and text inside, so I need it to look like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use css sprites.  http://jsfiddle.net/mCGXv/

Comment: That doesn't work as I need to change the background of the circle in the CSS code. It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Sure it can -- just create a whole bunch for all the background colors you're going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS sprites.

When you add an icon to the left of an `li`, be sure to increase the `padding-left` of the `li`, and you should be okay. I'm attaching a resource that should help you out.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/add-icon-before-after-link-css/

Comment: Doesn't work as I need to be able to change the color of the circle with code. It can't be set as an image.

Comment: Well, if you have a finite number of colors to use (5, 10, 100), you can bake those circle background images into a single sprite.

Comment: If you are a SET on using code for this, look into using the `:before` pseudo-element, adding a `background-color`, setting `position: relative` to the list item, and adjusting the `position:absolute` and `z-index` to move the colored box under the list item number. 

Since you need it to be a circle, just set `border-radius` (with vendor prefixes, if you support older browsers) to half the height/width of the `:before` pseudo-element square.